# Proxy (nginx) shows a Bad gateway error

Tags: proxy, nginx, gateway

I have a service (docker registry) that runs on `port 5000`, I have installed nginx to redirect http request from `8080` to `5000`. If I make a curl to `localhost:5000` it works, but when I make a curl to `localhost:8080` I get a **Bad gateway** error.

nginx config file:

```
upstream docker-registry {
 server localhost:5000;
}

server {
 listen 8080;
 server_name registry.mydomain.com;

 proxy_set_header Host       $http_host; 
 proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr; 
 client_max_body_size 0; 
 chunked_transfer_encoding on;

 location / {

     proxy_pass http://docker-registry;
 }
 location /_ping {
     auth_basic off;
     proxy_pass http://docker-registry;
 }
 location /v1/_ping {
     auth_basic off;
     proxy_pass http://docker-registry;
 }

}
```

In `/var/log/nginx/error.log` I have:

```
[crit] 15595#0: *1 connect() to [::1]:5000 failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: registry.mydomain.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://[::1]:5000/", host: "localhost:8080"
```

Any idea?

Comment: In my case, my service that I was proxying died (and I didn't realize it) in the middle of me using it. One second I was accessing it, the next second I got bad gateway. I had to restart the service.

Answer (score 59):

I assume its a Linux box, so most likely SELinux is preventing the connection as there is no policy allowing the connection.

You should be able to just run

`# setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect true`

and then restart nginx.

Comment: Selinux is disabled, also the service firewalld

Comment: You just fixed _my_ problem, even if you didn't fix hellb0y77's. SE_LINUX strikes again!

Comment: That worked for me too. Does anyone have any further information on what it's actually doing? I hate not knowing!

Comment: Upvoted and worked on centOs 7, can I ask what security issues this may open. I generally run a set of iptables rules which allow local traffic. Wondering what this effects.

Comment: @edencorbin it allows httpd modules to be able to connect to the network.

Comment: What does that mean @Warren? - i.e. is httpd a module run via Nginx?

Comment: @ZachSmith - it allows httpd services (in this case nginx) the ability to connect to the network. So in the original post, it would allow nginx to connect to port 5000.

Comment: solved my problem, thank's

Answer (score 5):

Based on the error message, it makes me wonder if localhost:5000 is being resolved as an ipv6 address, which you may not want. You could try changing that to 127.0.0.1:5000

*EDIT:* In your proxy_pass line, it is possible you are missing part of the URL? Try adding $request_uri so it could be:

```
proxy_pass http://docker-registry/$request_uri;
```

or probably:

```
proxy_pass http://docker-registry$request_uri;
```

Not sure which one is most correct.

Another thing to consider. Your config indicates:

```
server_name registry.mydomain.com;
```

So, localhost:8080 may not be matched.
For testing, you could change this to:

```
server_name registry.mydomain.com localhost;
```

Then the localhost:8080 would be matched, as well as your domain. I assume registry.mydomain.com is just an example and you would put your real server FQDN in there.

Comment: Not work, set `127.0.0.1:5000`and i have tried with only `server_name localhost` and `server_name registry.mydomain.com` (trying from another server in the same lan with hostname `registry.mydomain.com` in /etc/hosts), and both, but nothing...same error

Comment: Whit registry.mydomain.com `[crit] 16839#0: *5 connect() to 127.0.0.1:5000 failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: registry.mydomain,com request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/", host: "localhost:8080"`, with localhost: `[crit] 16839#0: *5 connect() to 127.0.0.1:5000 failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/", host: "localhost:8080"`